# How can I dynamically set an end date based on a given start date and term duration?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, date, datepicker

I want to dynamically set the Term End date based on the Term Type (annual, semiannual, quarter, month) and the Term Start date.

[image: Form]

So if we have a term that is set to annual and the start date is set to 03/10/2016, the term end should be set to 03/10/2017.

Here's what I have so far, but not sure how to work in casing the Term Type (annual == 12 months, etc.). I'm also getting a console error for the format of the date. Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
.field
  = f.label :term_start_date, 'Term Start', class: 'label'
  .input
    = f.date_field :term_start_date, id: 'termStart'
.field
  = f.label :term_end_date, 'Term End', class: 'label'
  .input
    = f.date_field :term_end_date, id: 'termEnd'
    :javascript
      $("#termStart").val();
      $("#termEnd").val({
          onSelect: function () {
              var toDate = $(this).val('getDate');
              toDate.setDate(toDate.getDate()+7)
              $("#termStart").val("setDate", toDate);
          }
      });
```

> The specified value "[object Object]" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: If you have a Date object, you can simply add one year: `date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() + 1)`. Note that 29 Feb plus one year will result in 1 Mar the following year. If you want 28 Feb you'll need to deal with that. You can use similar methods to add months, days, hours, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're attempting isn't difficult, but there's a bit of work to do. A date library can help, but it doesn't take a lot of effort to write your own methods. You need to do a few things:

1. Parse and validate the input start date
2. Get the term and add some months to the start date
3. Handle invalid input
4. Display the result

The following doesn't use any jQuery (you can use it if you like but it doesn't offer any benefits) and should give you some idea of what needs to be done.

```js
var dLib = {

  // Given a date string in format m/d/y, return a Date instance
  parseMDY: function (s) {
    var b = s.split(/\D+/);
    var d = new Date(b[2], --b[0], b[1]);
    return /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}/.test(s) &&
           d.getMonth() == b[0]? d : new Date(NaN);
  },

  // Given a Date, return date string formatted as mm/dd/yyyy
  formatMDY: function (date) {
    function z(n){return (n<10?'0':'')+n}
    if (isNaN(date)) return date.toString();
    return z(date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + z(date.getDate()) + '/' + date.getFullYear();
  },

  // Add months to a date. If end date itn's equal to start date,
  // must have gone past end of month so set to last day of month
  addMonths: function (date, months) {
    var startDate = date.getDate();
    date = new Date(+date);
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + Number(months))
    if (date.getDate() != startDate) {
      date.setDate(0);
    }
    return date;
  },
};

function setTermEnd(el) {
  var form = el.form;
  var term = form.termInMonths.value;
  var startDate = dLib.parseMDY(form.termStart.value);
  
  // Check that a valid date was entered. If no date entered
  // yet, do nothing. Else, put error message in termEnd
  if (isNaN(startDate)) {
    form.termEnd.value = form.termStart.value == ''? '' : 'Term start date is invalid';
    
  // Add months and set term end
  } else {
    form.termEnd.value = dLib.formatMDY(dLib.addMonths(startDate, term));
  }
}

// Attach listeners and run to initialise
window.onload = function() {
  var form = document.forms[0];
  form.termInMonths.onchange = function() {setTermEnd(this)};
  form.termStart.onchange = function() {setTermEnd(this)};
  form.termStart.onchange(form.termStart);
}
```

```css
.hint {
  color: #999999;
  font-size: 75%;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <table>
   <tr><td>Term:<td><select name="termInMonths">
                      <option value="12" selected>Annual
                      <option value="6">Semi-annual
                      <option value="3">Quarter
                      <option value="1">Month
                    </select>
   <tr><td>Term start:<td><input name="termStart" value="1/31/2016"><span class="hint">m/d/y</span>
   <tr><td>Term End:<td><input name="termEnd" readonly><span class="hint">m/d/y</span>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I actually prefer it with the vanilla js. As I'm continuing to learn js, I like to understand whats going on rather than use a library. Your answer is clear and has definitely helped me understand what I need to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's built-in datetime manipulation is very limited.

Your best bet is to use a javascript datetime library. moment.js is a good one

Your second best bet is going to be to work with the time in seconds as that is how javascript does it. Use Date.parse(toDate) to convert it to seconds since the epoch, then add the number of seconds, then convert it back to a date.

Comment: Using *Date.parse* (or the Date constructor, they are equivalent for parsing) is not recommended for parsing strings. Date objects have very robust methods for adding and subtracting values from any part of the date or time. They do lack a decent parser, good formatting and support for multiple time zones, but otherwise there's not much missing.

Comment: I stand corrected.

It's not actually made clear in the documentation that setting the month to '14' will cause it to be set to March next year, which is why I thought you would be looking at a fair bit of math to mess around with them in a safe way. However, for the purposes of this request that would indeed work.

Comment: "Not clear" is correct, but the result can be deduced by following the algorithm in [*§20.3.4.25*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.setmonth). The real work is done in [*§20.3.1.13*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-makeday), which allows months to be greater than 12 and days to be greater than the length of any particular month. :-)